# Require parameter naming to prevent ambiguity on same-ish looking parameter list

Tags: c#, oop, arguments, ambiguous

Consider the following definition:

```cs
class Foo
{
    string Asd;
    List<int> Qwert;

    public Foo(string Bar, List<int> Baz = null)
    {
        // Set up instance from parameters
        this.Asd = Bar;
        this.Qwert = Baz ?? new List<int>;
    }

    public Foo(string Qwop)
    {
        // Code which sets up the instance based on what Qwop is
        // E.g.: take Asd and Qwert values from a previous storage
    }
}
```

Now if I invoke the constructor as `Foo foo = new Foo("value");` the second constructor is executed.

How can I make the compiler force the invocation with named parameters? Because both constructors' first argument is a `string`, there is a clear ambiguity. (I cannot escape or workaround the fact that either way, we need to take a `string`.)

```cs
Foo foo = new Foo("value"); // NOT fine
Foo foo = new Foo(Bar: "value"); // Fine, first constructor
Foo foo = new Foo("value", new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 }; // Fine, as it is clearly 1st
Foo foo = new Foo(Qwop: "anothervalue"); // Fine, second constructor
```

I thought about declaring an extra constructor:

```cs
[Obsolete("Parameterization would be ambiguos. Please specify what string is by using named parameters", true)]
public Foo(string param)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

I thought this would mean that without named parameters, the code would call this one and compiling would fail. But the build failed earlier, because

> Type 'Program.Foo' already defines a member called 'Foo' with the same parameter types

So apparently, this is a no-go. But my other try:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public Foo(IFooInvoker invoker)
    {
        if (invoker is FooInvokerBarBaz) { ... }
        else if (invoker is FooInvokerQwop) { ... }
    }
}

interface IFooInvoker { ... }

class FooInvokerBarBaz : IFooInvoker { ... }
class FooInvokerQwop : IFooInvoker { ... }

// And calling the whole from Main by
Foo foo = new Foo(new FooInvokerBarBaz("bar", new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 });
// or
Foo foo = new Foo(new FooInvokerQwop("qwop");
```

Looks **way** too complicated, is ugly and I think violates more than one design principles.

Comment: Nit: you're using the terms "parameter" and "argument" the wrong way round. A method declares its parameters; the call site supplies arguments. (You're actually looking for named arguments, not named parameters. *All* parameters are named.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I make the compiler force the invocation with named parameters?

You can't, basically. It's just not part of the language.

What you *can* do is make the constructors private, and instead expose static factory methods, which explain what they're constructing an instance from.

```
public static Foo FromBarAndBaz(string bar, List<int> baz = null)
{
    return new Foo(bar, baz);
}

public static Foo FromQwop(string qwop)
{
    return new Foo(qwop);
}
```

(You'd probably want to make `baz` mandatory in the *constructor* too, for simplicity.)

Note that I've changed the parameter names to comply with normal .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Static factories. That's what I forgot. The same thing I wrote about Tim's answer applies to you too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. C# just doesn't support it. You could make your signatures less similar, e.g.

```
public Foo(string bar, List<int> baz) // baz is now required, but can be null
public Foo(string qwop)
```

Or you could make the constructors private and expose static methods:

```
private Foo(string bar, List<int> baz)
private Foo(string qwop)
public static Foo FromBarBaz(string bar, List<int> baz = null)
public static Foo FromQwop(string qwop)
```

(as a minor note, parameters [should be camelCased](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229004%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not PascalCased)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's unfortunate, I'll look for another way around. (Although I use camelCasing in the code, it was a misbehaviour from me to not to do so.)